# ERROR java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Informatica Cloud

Tags: cloud, informatica

I was running a Informatica Cloud mapping task perfectly.

Now, i try to run this job and I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.boot.PluginFactory.loadAndInitialize(PluginFactory.java:98)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.boot.PluginFactory.getPluginProxy(PluginFactory.java:24)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.boot.CCIBootPlugin.<init>(CCIBootPlugin.java:30)
at com.infa.adapter.bigquery.cci.deploy.BigqueryPlugin.<init>(BigqueryPlugin.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.utils.Utils.unifiedClassLoadingApplicable(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.utils.Utils.getClassLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.initWriteOperation(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.init(Unknown Source)
```

That is an other error that appears in the middle of the log:

```
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2021-09-21 20:14:18.173] [ERROR] Caused by: com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.exceptions.OsgiWrapperException: [OSGIWRAPPER_00001] Internal error. A repository internal error occurred: '[OSGIWRAPPER_00003] Internal error. A repository internal error occurred while installing the bundle from the following location: '/infacloud/infaagent/downloads/package-CCIAgent.3701201/package/ICS/main/cci/plugins/infa/atlanticRuntimeBDM-tpls.jar': 'An error occurred trying to read the bundle'. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support.'. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support.
at com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.OsgiWrapper.startFramework(OsgiWrapper.java:331)
at com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.OsgiWrapper.startFramework(OsgiWrapper.java:338)
at com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.OsgiWrapper.init(OsgiWrapper.java:259)
at com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.OsgiWrapper.init(OsgiWrapper.java:163)
at com.informatica.sdk.adapter.utils.impl.OSGiUtilsImpl.osgiInit(OSGiUtilsImpl.java:55)
at com.informatica.sdk.adapter.utils.impl.OSGiUtilsImpl.osgiInit(OSGiUtilsImpl.java:82)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.utils.CCIUtils.initialize(CCIUtils.java:65)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.plugin.CCIPluginCache.<init>(CCIPluginCache.java:46)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.plugin.CCIPluginCache.getInstance(CCIPluginCache.java:93)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.plugin.CCIPluginProxy.<init>(CCIPluginProxy.java:60)

Caused by: com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.exceptions.OsgiWrapperException: [OSGIWRAPPER_00003] Internal error. A repository internal error occurred while installing the bundle from the following location: '/infacloud/infaagent/downloads/package-CCIAgent.3701201/package/ICS/main/cci/plugins/infa/atlanticRuntimeBDM-tpls.jar': 'An error occurred trying to read the bundle'. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support.
at com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.OsgiWrapper.installBundle(OsgiWrapper.java:585)
at com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.OsgiWrapper.installBundles(OsgiWrapper.java:529)
at com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.OsgiWrapper.startFramework(OsgiWrapper.java:293)
... 29 more

JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2021-09-21 20:14:18.174] [ERROR] Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: An error occurred trying to read the bundle
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.stageContent0(Storage.java:867)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.stageContent(Storage.java:823)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.install(Storage.java:525)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:146)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:139)
at com.informatica.osgi.wrapper.OsgiWrapper.installBundle(OsgiWrapper.java:583)
... 31 more
```

That is an other error that appears in the middle of the log:

```
[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2026)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.stageContent0(Storage.java:847)
... 36 more
```

That is an other error that appears in the middle of the log:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.boot.PluginFactory.loadAndInitialize(PluginFactory.java:98)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.boot.PluginFactory.getPluginProxy(PluginFactory.java:24)
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.boot.CCIBootPlugin.<init>(CCIBootPlugin.java:30)
at com.infa.adapter.bigquery.cci.deploy.BigqueryPlugin.<init>(BigqueryPlugin.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.utils.Utils.getPluginInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.initGroupOperation(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.init(Unknown Source)
```

That is an other error that appears in the middle of the log:

```
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2021-09-21 20:14:18.277] [ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.informatica.platform.adaptersdk.extpointmgr.ModelAttributesExtensionHelper.populateSDKDefaultModelAttributes(ModelAttributesExtensionHelper.java:439)
    at com.informatica.platform.adaptersdk.extpointmgr.ModelAttributesExtensionHelper.<init>(ModelAttributesExtensionHelper.java:190)
    at com.informatica.platform.adaptersdk.extpointmgr.ExtensionManager.getInstance(ExtensionManager.java:128)
    at com.informatica.cci.reginfo.impl.AdapterImpl.<init>(AdapterImpl.java:35)
    at com.informatica.cci.reginfo.impl.AdapterInfoImpl.getAdapterById(AdapterInfoImpl.java:65)
    at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.plugin.CCIPluginCache.<init>(CCIPluginCache.java:52)
    at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.plugin.CCIPluginCache.getInstance(CCIPluginCache.java:93)
    at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.plugin.CCIPluginProxy.<init>(CCIPluginProxy.java:60)
    ... 19 more
    [ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.boot.CCIBootPlugin.setLogger(CCIBootPlugin.java:96)
    at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.initGroupOperation(Unknown Source)
    at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.init(Unknown Source)
```

Have you had those errors and how did you fix it?

Comment: 1. see if you are missing any files to remove `file not found` error. 2. Do you have any plugin/Power exchange - chekc if theya re properly set/used in mapping.

Comment: Thank you, @KoushikRoy. The problem was solved. Was just a bug with informatica cloud that crash all the taskflow.